# Pass file to child flow (email template)

Tags: flow, power-automate, attachments

Currently I have two flows:

1. Email Template: accepts variables for text, subject, files (separate variables for SharePoint name & path)
2. "call flow": runs through list with emailadresses and names, passes these to child flow to send email

Now I'm running into problems when adding attachments. I used [this guide](https://www.powerautomatetraining.co.uk/post/microsoft-flow-retrieve-all-files-from-sharepoint-library-folder-send-email-attachment) (other guides suggest the same solution) to pass the file data in the template flow as attachment. The mail get's send properly including the attachment **but** the file is corrupt, much larger than the original file and can't be opened.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: condition in child flow to check if file path is used and then generate the attachment array]
*condition in child flow to check if file path is used and then generate the attachment array*

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. It's only for max 1 attachment, but it works fine.

### First I created the child flow which sends the email:

[image]

It has variables for email-adress, subject and text. In addition it has a file variable, which holds the filecontent and a text variable which will be used as the attachments filename.

### Then I creates the "call" flow:

[image]

The SharePoint action is the one to get a **file from path** (I renamed it in the image), not the usual one.
To pass it as valide content to the child flow, you need to write an expression like this

```
body('Lade_Datei').$content
```

and put it into the *contentByte* variable. The desired filename should be written in the extra generated variable field (in this case 'Dateiname' **not** 'Datiinhalt name').

Now when the email is send the attachment is not corrupted and works.